# SQL: JOIN multiple tables with different size

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

I am not someone who works a lot with database so the answer can be easy but I am unable to find it.
Here is a simplified version of my database (which is in **SQLITE** btw):
[image: database image]

I have the following values in my database (I only put the id here because only them are relevant):

- device.id: 1, 2, 3
- capability.id: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
- action.id: 100, 200, 300, 400, 500
- action.id_capability: 10, 30, 40, 10, 50

And here are entries in map_device_cap:

- 1, 10
- 1, 30
- 1, 40
- 2, 10
- 2, 20
- 2, 50
- 3, 20

Entries in map_device_action:

- 1, 100
- 1, 200
- 1, 300
- 2, 400
- 2, 500

Now I want to create SELECT request that group tables map_device_cap and map_device_action. In this case the result will be:

- 1, 10, 100
- 1, 30, 200
- 1, 40, 300
- 2, 10, 400
- 2, 20, null
- 2, 50, 500
- 3, 20, null

**NOTE**: the table map_device_cap will ALWAYS be larger than map_device_action.

I have first try the following request:

```
SELECT map_device_cap.id_device, map_device_cap.id_capability,
       map_device_action.id_action 
FROM map_device_cap NATURAL LEFT JOIN map_device_action
```

But this request gave me the following result:

- 1, 10, 100
- 1, 10, 200
- 1, 10, 300
- 1, 30, 100
- 1, 30, 200
- 1, 30, 300
- 1, 40, 100
- 1, 40, 200
- 1, 40, 300
- 2, 10, 400
- 2, 10, 500
- 2, 20, 400
- 2, 20, 500
- 2, 50, 400
- 2, 50, 500
- 3, 20, null

As you can see there are duplicates entries and I don't know how to remove them.

If anyone has an idea or need more information, please let me know.

Regards

Comment: Please provide data from "Action" table as well.

Comment: I provided them but just for a reminder:
action.id: 100, 200, 300, 400, 500
action.id_capability: 10, 30, 40, 10, 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT mdc.id_device,
       mdc.id_capability,
       (SELECT (mda.id_action) 
         FROM action a 
         JOIN map_device_action mda 
              ON a.id_capability = mdc.id_capability 
              AND a.id = mda.id_action
              AND mda.id_device = mdc.id_device
        ) as a
FROM map_device_cap mdc
ORDER BY mdc.id_device,  mdc.id_capability;
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is like this

```
SELECT c.id_device,
       c.id_capability,
       a.id
FROM #map_device_cap c
     JOIN #action a ON c.id_capability = a.id_capability
     JOIN #map_device_action ma ON a.id = ma.id_action
                                   AND c.id_device = ma.id_device
UNION
SELECT c.id_device,
       c.id_capability,
       NULL
FROM #map_device_cap c
     LEFT JOIN #map_device_action ma ON c.id_device = ma.id_device
WHERE ma.id_device IS NULL;
```

Complete Script which I used for my testing:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#map_device_cap') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #map_device_cap;

CREATE TABLE #map_device_cap
(id_device INT,
 id_capability       INT
);

INSERT INTO #map_device_cap
VALUES
(1,
 10
);

INSERT INTO #map_device_cap
VALUES
(1,
 30
);

INSERT INTO #map_device_cap
VALUES
(1,
 40
);
INSERT INTO #map_device_cap
VALUES
(2,
 10
);
INSERT INTO #map_device_cap
VALUES
(2,
 50
);
INSERT INTO #map_device_cap
VALUES
(3,
 20
);

select * from #map_device_cap

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#map_device_action') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #map_device_action;

CREATE TABLE #map_device_action(id_device INT,
 id_action       INT);

INSERT INTO #map_device_action
VALUES
(1,
 100
);

INSERT INTO #map_device_action
VALUES
(1,
 200
);

INSERT INTO #map_device_action
VALUES
(1,
 300
);

INSERT INTO #map_device_action
VALUES
(2,
 400
);

INSERT INTO #map_device_action
VALUES
(2,
 500
);


select * from #map_device_action


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#action') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #action;

CREATE TABLE #action(id INT,
 id_capability       INT);

INSERT INTO #action
VALUES
(100,
 10
);

INSERT INTO #action
VALUES
(200,
 30
);

INSERT INTO #action
VALUES
(300,
 40
);

INSERT INTO #action
VALUES
(400,
 10
);

INSERT INTO #action
VALUES
(500,
 50
);


SELECT c.id_device,
       c.id_capability,
       a.id
FROM #map_device_cap c
     JOIN #action a ON c.id_capability = a.id_capability
     JOIN #map_device_action ma ON a.id = ma.id_action
                                   AND c.id_device = ma.id_device
UNION
SELECT c.id_device,
       c.id_capability,
       NULL
FROM #map_device_cap c
     LEFT JOIN #map_device_action ma ON c.id_device = ma.id_device
WHERE ma.id_device IS NULL;
```

**Updated Query to meet your needs:**

```
SELECT c.id_device,
       c.id_capability,
       a.id
FROM map_device_cap c
      JOIN action a ON c.id_capability = a.id_capability
      JOIN map_device_action ma ON a.id = ma.id_action
                                   AND c.id_device = ma.id_device
UNION
SELECT c.id_device,
       c.id_capability,
       NULL
FROM map_device_cap c
     LEFT JOIN map_device_action ma ON c.id_device = ma.id_device
WHERE ma.id_device IS NULL
UNION
SELECT c.id_device,
       c.id_capability,
       NULL
FROM map_device_cap c
     LEFT JOIN action a ON c.id_capability = a.id_capability
WHERE a.id_capability IS NULL;
```

Comment: This solution does not works when a device possess 2 capabilities but only 1 action (map_device_cap for device.id = x return 2 entries but map_device_action for device.id = x return 1 entry).
Thank you for your help. This is almost perfect

Comment: I just update my example, then you can easily see it yourself